# POST form values over HTTPS

Tags: encryption, https, hash

I'm fairly unfamiliar with HTTPS, but I know it's secure, what I want to know is when a user logs in with details on a form, are the variables in that form (username, password) sent to the server encrypted?

I'm asking this, as I'm using a form to log people in, but I'm also hashing their passwords with MD5 together with a SALT for verification.

Also, is HTTPS secure enough to prevent any spyware running on the host from intercepting the login details?

Sorry for asking a few questions in this post, but thanks in advance for any answers.

Comment: MD5 is insecure.  Do not use it.

Comment: I see Joomla uses MD5 with SALT (as I'm doing), is this then ineffective? I also use multiple hashing, first hashing the (password) and then hashing the (password.salt). What other hashing do you recommend?

Comment: @SLaks why everyone is afraid of MD5, especially that SALT is involved in the encryption

Comment: I hope you're using cryptographically secure per-user random _byte sequences_ (not ASCII) as salt.  BTW, salt is not an acronym and should not be capitalized.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I'm fairly unfamiliar with HTTPS, but I know it's secure, what I want to know is when a user logs in with details on a form, are the variables in that form (username, password) sent to the server encrypted?

The entirety of the HTTP request and response are encrypted.

The DNS look-up to convert the hostname to an IP address will, however, not be.

> Also, is HTTPS secure enough to prevent any spyware running on the host from intercepting the login details?

No. HTTPS encrypts the communication between the client and the server. It cannot prevent software on the client from interfering with the request or reading the response. This includes the possibility of an attacker intercepting the request for the form and modifying it — so the form must be sent over SSL too.

Comment: The initial request url query params will not be encrypted

Comment: @gawpertron — Wrong. If it sent over HTTPS then the query string will be encrypted.

Answer (score 4):

OK.  Let's break this question up a bit and cover a few things here.

First: you say that you know that HTTPS is "secure".  Let's qualify that a bit.

HTTPS is an encryption mechanism, and nothing more than that, so using HTTPS in itself does not guarantee "security" in any broader sense.  If you're using HTTPS, all you know, really, is that whatever information is sent from your visitor's browser to your server will be sent over an encrypted communication channel, such as to protect against [Man-in-the-Middle Attacks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-in-the-middle_attack).

While that is essential, using encryption/HTTPS in **no way** protects you from any other number of other potential vulnerabilities, including broken authentication mechanisms, SQL injections, Cross-Site Scripting (XSS), and a host of others.

If you're interesting in learning more about Information Security in General, I'd strongly recommend that you read [Secrets and Lies](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0471453803) by Bruce Schneier, who is a well-respected security authority.  The book is a bit old now, but the information it contains has aged very well, in my opinion.

Second: Just to be explicit, using HTTPS will in **no way** protect you from Spyware, etc.  Remember that HTTPS merely ensures encrypted communications, but can do nothing more than that.

Third: As SLaks has said, MD5 is probably not the best hashing algorithm to use anymore.  While I'm not an expert on cryptography by any means, I think you're still reasonably safe if you use SHA1 (plus a strong [salt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salt_(cryptography))) instead.  To the best of my knowledge, MD5 has suffered some mathematical defeats over the last few years which has weakened its security.

If you're interested in learning the nitty-gritty details of web security, I'd also strongly recommend [The Web Application Hacker's Handbook](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0470170778), which I consider to be an excellent primer on the subject.

I hope that's helpful.

Answer (score 2):

All data sent to and from the server in an HTTPS request is encrypted.
This include the URL, headers, POST data, and response.

If your enemy has code running on either endpoint, he's already defeated you.
There is nothing you can do about it that he can't beat.

Comment: We'll assume the hosting server is secure, but is there any way then to protect on the client side?

Comment: No; not at all.  You could offer free anti-virus software and hope that your users install it.

Answer (score 2):

`HTTPs` is a protocol used to prevent watching the data being sent between you and the server by ISPs or public WIFI hijackers and other cases, It may not prevent a spyware on your server to read it, To post data using SSL you only need to set the `action` attribute to a full `https://` end url assuming you already installed an SSL certificate.

From Wikipedia:

> Hypertext Transfer Protocol Secure
>   (HTTPS) is a combination of the
>   Hypertext Transfer Protocol with the
>   SSL/TLS protocol to provide encrypted
>   communication and secure
>   identification of a network web
>   server.

About the `MD5`, I believe that your combination of `MD5` And `SALT` technique is fairly secure and it prevents hackers to easily find popular passwords if they gained access to your database.

Answer (score 1):

HTTPS is certainly secure for traffic in both directions (assuming you keep the private key secure).  Spyware could compromise the private key and thus the security of HTTPS traffic to the host.

Answer (score 1):

The purpose of HTTPS is used to maintain these three fundamental information security needs:

- [*Confidentiality*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Information_security#Confidentiality) – Only the recipient can read the transmitted message that was meant for him/her.
- [*Integrity*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Information_security#Integrity) – Recipient can detect whether the transmitted message got compromised.
- [*Authenticity*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Information_security#Authenticity) – Recipient can verify that the transmitted message is from the sender.

That’s it. Note that this does only apply for the *transmitted message*. What is being sent and what happens with the data on the sender’s and recipient’s side is out of scope as HTTPS does only protect the transmission channel.

Particularly this means that it is possible that for example

- the sender sends already malicious data over an HTTPS protected channel
- the recipient receives sensible data over an HTTPS protected channel but there is spyware on the machine that can read the data.

So to answer your two questions:

> […] when a user logs in with details on a form, are the variables in that form (username, password) sent to the server encrypted?

Yes, if you use HTTPS for the transmission the transmitted data is encrypted by the client and only the server can decrypt it.

> Also, is HTTPS secure enough to prevent any spyware running on the host from intercepting the login details?

No, as already said, HTTPS does only protect the data transmission from the sender to the recipient. Anything beyond that is out of scope.